Powershell: set new task under taskscheduler from Intune
I need to use powershell script to set schedule task. The test users has an admin rights and running manually works on user's test pc, creates the scheduled task.
However the other users doesnt have admin rights and if I send it from Intune it doesnt run. Intune only says its status is 'failed'.
I tried to use different log on time and run level.
Here is my script (part of set task under scheduler):
**# Define the action for the scheduled task**

$taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe" -Argument '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\\Temp\\appremove.ps1"'

**# Define the trigger to run the task at logon for any user**

$taskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn

$taskSettings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries

*New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId $currentUser -LogonType Interactive -RunLevel Limited*

**# Register the scheduled task**

Register-ScheduledTask -Action $taskAction -Trigger $taskTrigger -TaskName $taskName -User $currentUser -Settings $taskSettings

**# Display a confirmation message**

Write-Host "Scheduled task has been created to run '$scriptPath' at every logon for any user."


To clarify, have you tried running the task with the highest privileges instead of limited? Does it create the task as expected?
Additionally, have you considered running the task under the SYSTEM account instead of the logged-in user’s account?
You can also check the IME logs on the device to understand why the PowerShell script failed. The logs are located at: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\IntuneManagementExtension\Logs. For more details, you can refer to the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/intune-management-extension

Remove the -atlogon bit. For that you need admin rights. Use an other trigger. Like every 4 hours.
